# Dreamhost closed my domain for excessive resources usage

Tags: shared-hosting, memory-usage, joomla, dreamhost

I come directly from stackoverflow, and is my first time posting here!

I manage many domains on dreamhost for my NGO (non-governative-organization). some days ago dreamhost disabled (with very short advise) 3 of my subdomains for resources over use.

here's their email:

> It seems
>   that a good deal of the system's load was originating from your
>   domain's sism.org, nazionale.sism.org, and bologna.sism.org.
>
> It also seems that your sites are being killed by our Process Watcher
>   script for going over memory limits, which will cause Internal Server
>   Errors:
>
> Wed Sep 21 11:39:15 2011 procwatch3 INFO: PID 13762 (php5.cgi)
>   sismbologna:pg1971200 - 27.2MB ram, 0.73 sec cpu: killed for uid ram
>
> Wed Sep 21 11:39:15 2011 procwatch3 INFO: PID 13887 (php5.cgi)
>   sismbologna:pg1971200 - 23.7MB ram, 0.22 sec cpu: killed for uid ram
>
> Wed Sep 21 11:39:26 2011 procwatch3 INFO: PID 14468 (php5.cgi)
>   sismbologna:pg1971200 - 2.7MB ram, 0.00 sec cpu [idle php]: killed for
>   uid ram
>
> Wed Sep 21 11:39:26 2011 procwatch3 INFO: PID 14454 (php5.cgi)
>   sismbologna:pg1971200 - 23.7MB ram, 0.21 sec cpu: killed for uid ram
>
> Wed Sep 21 11:39:26 2011 procwatch3 INFO: PID 14073 (php5.cgi)
>   sismbologna:pg1971200 - 23.7MB ram, 0.22 sec cpu: killed for uid ram

First question: I have one one first level domain, www.sism.org, that is mapped to the subdomain nazionale.sism.org, and I have a folder in my user that is called sism.org, but is not mapped to any domain. They wrote that both sism.org and nazionale.sism.org were giving problems. Is this because they are both mapped to the same domain so the problem is one?

Second question: the user in which is nazionale.sism.org has many other domains in it. Do at dreamhost asses the usage of all the user of just domain by domain? i mean, having more domains per user could create the resource problem or they only care about the domain and not the user?

Third: this websites are based on joomla and for the nazionale.sism.org one i have ~280 accesses every day. is this too much for a shared server?

Fourth: is there a way to check which script in my joomla sites is create this memory problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

1. Who knows except Dreamhost?
2. Who knows except Dreamhost?
3. Who knows except you? You have the contract and the given limits. If 280 accesses are above the limit then yes.
4. Not after it got killed. While running you can see several information of a PID under `/proc/$PID`. For example `/proc/$PID/cmdline`.

Comment: I don't have a fixed limit. i'm on a shared server, the limit is decided dynamically i suppose. As for the questions 1 & 2, i'm asking because maybe someone here has experience about how Dreamhost manage this stuff